# fail to add Chinese punctuation after CJKnumber in chatper title in xeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, punctuation, xecjk

I'm writing my thesis in Chinese with xeLaTeX and I've to format the chapter name and section name.

The following command works ok:

```
 \usepackage[CJKnumber][xeCJK]
 \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\CJKnumber{\thechapter}}
```

except that I still need to add Chinese punctuation after the number. e.g

```
  一、第一章
 （一） 第一节
```

the compiler would complain `! Missing number, treated as zero.` if I did so:

```
 \usepackage[CJKnumber][xeCJK]
 \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\CJKnumber、{\thechapter}}
```

Any ideas to work around this ?

example:

```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage[CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
  \usepackage{titlesec}

  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\CJKnumber{\thechapter}、} 
  \titleformat{\chapter}{\xiaosihao\hei}{\chaptername}{0.1em}{}
  \newcommand{\sectionname}{（\CJKnumber{\thesection}）}  
  \titleformat{\section}{\xiaosihao\hei}{\sectionname}{0.1em}{} 

  \begin{document}
  \chapter{第一章}
  \section{第一节}
  \end{document}
```

I'm able to get chapter name to work now but section number turns out to be `（.1 一）` instead of `（一）`

Comment: I guess that `\CJKnumber{\thechapter}、` should do.

Comment: @egreg yes it works. would you please elaborate your answer below? How about the section name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\CJKnumber` has an argument that should expand to a number, so that it can be converted to the Chinese system.

Thus `\CJKnumber{1}` is legal, as it is `\CJKnumber{\thechapter}`: the whole lot is "the number".

Since you want the punctuation mark *after* the number, the construction

```
\CJKnumber{\thechapter}、
```

is what you're looking for.

You probably want something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Kai}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{章}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\CJKnumber{\arabic{chapter}}、} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
  （\CJKnumber{\arabic{chapter}}、 %
    \CJKnumber{\arabic{section}}）}

\begin{document}
\chapter{第一章}
\section{第一节}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: another issue is to replace section number like 1.1 with （一），what I get with `（\CJKnumber{\thesection}）` is （.1 一）

Comment: @manuzhang Please, add a minimal example to your question starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` so it's possible to play with it.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: what does `\arabic` do here?

Comment: @manuzhang `\arabic{section}` produces the decimal representation of the counter's value. You can also use `\value{section}` if you prefer, so `\CJKnumber` will use the "abstract" value.

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD read the document of `ctex` package and follow it. Don't use the low level macros. `titlesec` is useful for more complex chapter title formats, but it is overkill here.

And further more, `CJKnumber` option is now somewhat obsolete for new documents, since `zhnumber` works better than old `CJKNumb` package. New version of `ctex` uses `zhnumber` internally as well.

```
\documentclass{ctexrep}
\CTEXsetup[name={,、},number=\chinese{chapter},aftername={}]{chapter}
\CTEXsetup[name={（,）},number=\chinese{section},aftername={}]{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{第一章}
\section{第一节}
\end{document}
```